# Comparison of two different ratings of ten variables

Tags: excel

I am rating the quality of a product across ten dimensions D1 to D10, e.g., durability, price, advertising, etc. Each dimension receives a rating from 1 to 10 (1 = lowest, 10 = highest). I have a main supervisor (S) conduct his rating and then ask several people (P1, P2) to do their own rating.

```
    S   P1   P2
D1  5    6    5
D2  4    4    3
D3  9    10   8
...
```

How can I say something about the validity of S's rating given the opinions of P1 and P2? How would I do this in Excel?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

Validity is about whether your measurements (here, ratings of quality) are measuring what you think they are rating.

If there is agreement among the three raters, that is at least *some* evidence of the validity, but it's not all that compelling. That suggests two approaches, given what you have:  You could look at correlations among the three people or you could look at the absolute values of the differences among the three people. If the correlations are high and the differences are small, that would be good.

Comment: Somebody at work suggested Spearman rank. Isn't there a statistical method other than simple correlation to vaildate the ratings?

Comment: I suggested two methods.  But, really, validation is an involved process and you don't have much data.  Validating a rating scale would, ideally, include comparing the ratings to some objective measure.